# jquery events not executing associated with ember.js app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js

I'm building an ember.js app using rails.My index.html contains the templates to be rendered.The issue is when jquery gets called jquery ready event is executing but further events inside it are not working.
views/hello.js is:

```
$(function(){
alert("hello");
$("#addTask").click(function(){
alert("add task");
});  
});
```

the first alert msg is executing but the click event is not getting called.

index.html is:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">           
{{outlet}}          
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
<p>rendering index template</p>
<button type='button' id='addTask' class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add Task</button>
</script>
```

the application.js has

```
/= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require handlebars
//= require ember
//= require ember-data
//= require views/hello
//= require views/app
```

views/app.js

var app1 = Ember.Application.create();

Answer (score 0):

Without your full source, no one can give you a proper answer.

Have you considered [delegated events](https://api.jquery.com/on/), where your `click` handler is registered to every current and future elements, so it doesn't matter when ember.js renders your button (because ember is rendering it for you)?

```
$("document").on("click", "#addTask", function () {
    alert("add task");
});
```

Comment: tried using the .on() method but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: does ember have a dependency on any particular version of jquery,which is causing the problem?i have used the jquery-rails gem

Comment: No, that is not the issue... my second suspicion would be that you should really be obeying Ember's [template handler](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/handling-events/) convention -- not making your own random jquery events. One can guess.

Comment: yes,the issue was i was creating my own jquery events and not using the ember way of handling events by defining actions property array in controller and many such conventions.Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

index.html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">           
{{outlet}}          
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
<p>rendering index template</p>
<button {{action 'addtask'}}>Add Task</button>
</script>
```

in app.js where controller is defined

```
 var app1 = Ember.Application.create();
 app1.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
 actions: {
 addtask: function() {
  alert("click event handled");
   }
   }
 });
```

by using ember's {{action}} helper events can be handled http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Ember.run.bind()

Basically, you want ember to throw your jquery event in the Ember run loop.  So that it gets executed appropriately once your ember code has run.

Check out this nice post about it.

http://balinterdi.com/2014/05/09/ember-dot-run-dot-bind.html